# Is getaddrinfo with AI_NUMERICHOST flag non-blocking?

Tags: python

I'm using `socket.getaddrinfo()` in an asynchronous program. In order to prevent blocking inside the function, I'm running it in a separate thread. That is an overhead I'd like to reduce when possible.

The question is: **Is it correct to assume that disabling DNS will make `getaddrinfo()` non-blocking?** There is a flag for disabling DNS:

> AI_NUMERICHOST will disable domain name resolution and will raise an
>   error if host is a domain name

The program logic would be:

1. try to call `getaddrinfo` directly with the `AI_NUMERICHOST` flag
2. if it fails, create a new thread calling `getaddrinfo` without that flag